# How to join and apply within the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
|--------|---------|----------------|
|   ID   |  Value  |  AssociatedID  |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    1   |   Val 1 |      3         |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    2   |   Val 2 |      4         |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    3   |         |                |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    4   |         |                |
|--------|---------|----------------|
```

The Output that I want is

```
|--------|---------|----------------|
|   ID   |  Value  |  AssociatedID  |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    1   |   Val 1 |      3         |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    2   |   Val 2 |      4         |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    3   |   Val 1 |                |
|--------|---------|----------------|
|    4   |   Val 2 |                |
|--------|---------|----------------|
```

So Basically I want to do a join between the Associated ID and ID field and apply the Value.

The basic way in which I could do this is

```
for id in df['AssociatedID'].unique.tolist():
    valueToApply = df.loc[df['AssociatedID'] == id]["ID"].values
    df.loc[(df['ID'] == id) , "Value"] = valueToApply
```

I was hoping I could use some sort of pandas one liner to achieve this. What is the best way to do it with pandas? any one line code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `np.where` with `map`

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'].isnull(), 
                       df['ID'].map(dict(zip(df['AssociatedID'],df['Value']))), 
                       df['Value'])
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the following error, the first argument should be a callable function.

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent import numpy as np

Comment: I have imported it

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent it is works fine on my side, can you try restart you ide and check your sample again ?

Comment: Can you please explain what the map line does?

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent map is to use ID to check `AssociatedID` column, if found then return the `Value` at the same row, if not return NaN~